# Box api call returning 403 forbidden error in Vue but the same URL working in postman

Tags: vue.js, xmlhttprequest, axios, postman, box-api

I have a developer token for box and the box app all set up. when I use Postman I get the data that I am looking for returned. I have looked at the headers that Postman is sending and have provided the same in my code.

```
axios({
    async: true,
    crossDomain: true,
    url: 'https://api.box.com/2.0/files/<File ID>/',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Postman-Token': '<Postman Token>',
      'cache-control': 'no-cache',
      Authorization: 'Bearer <Developer Token>',
      Accept: '*/*',
    },
  }).then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
  }).catch(console.error);
```

This returns a 403 in the browser.

This is the Response Headers from Postman:

```
Date:"Wed, 03 Apr 2019 06:04:45 GMT"
Content-Type:"application/json"
Transfer-Encoding:"chunked"
Connection:"keep-alive"
Strict-Transport-Security:"max-age=31536000"
Cache-Control:"no-cache, no-store"
ETag:""0""
Content-Encoding:"gzip"
Vary:"Accept-Encoding"
BOX-REQUEST-ID:"<BOX-REQUEST-ID>"
Age:"0"
```

Response Headers from bowser

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Age: 0
BOX-REQUEST-ID: <BOX-REQUEST-ID>
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Wed, 03 Apr 2019 06:36:01 GMT
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Origin,Accept-Encoding
```

Error in browser dev tools

```
GET https://api.box.com/2.0/files/<File ID>/ 403 (Forbidden)
Error: Request failed with status code 403
    at createError (createError.js?2d83:16)
    at settle (settle.js?467f:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js?b50d:77)
```

Comment: Can you share the response body and headers?

Comment: What @Kordonme said. You can inspect the response body and headers using the Network pane in browser devtools. Along with that, what are the exact errors the browser is logging in the devtools console?

Comment: @Kordonme question is updated

Comment: Could you share with me the request ID from the error body? Then I'll look up for you what the cause is. (I'm a Box employee)

Comment: @CristianoBetta - 0oedp6gb3leo8qoij1l1263gjn8

Comment: Hmmm, I can not find that request ID. Did you use the same developer token for both calls?

Comment: Yea I did. The problem that I have found is that Box API won’t allow me to whitelist localhost:8080. And that’s why I am getting this. I need to find a way to whitelist a url with a port number.